# Creating 3*3 grid using the new GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid

Is it possible to create a 3*3 grid using the new GridLayout in ICS. I tried many methods like specifying the rowCount and columnCount to 3. I just cant figure out the basics of gridlayout.

**I want to create a grid where layout splits the available space into equal sized cells.**

I was able to create an icon grid but the size was not equal. Each cell took the size of the icon.

I am not looking into alternate layouts as I am trying to figure out how the GridLayout is used.

Comment: Maybe you can post the layout you tried as a starting point.

Comment: I dont have the code anymore kept overwriting the xml file with new stuff. But it seems the gridlayout doesnt really do what's on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really more [TableLayout's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) bag.  GridLayout is meant to help flatten what can otherwise become deeply nested view hierarchies.  [This blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) gives a great overview of what it's good at and why it's there.  Notice how in diagrams, GridLayout's grid is snapping to the sizes of the various views inside of it.

If you absolutely wanted to use GridLayout instead of TableLayout to accomplish the layout you're describing anyway, one (slightly hackish) solution would be to just create 9 copies of a fixed view, set them to (available width / 3) x (available height / 3), and add them as children to the GridLayout.  But, one more time, this isn't the case GridLayout is for.

Comment: Well I did see the blog post. My first trials were based on that. My concept for the gridlayout isn't really what is in android right now. There is a gridlayout created by romain guy for his photostream application that does exactly what I wanted. http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/GridLayout.java. But there are some issues im trying to figure out. Guess Ill have to make that another question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was trying to do a similar thing with GridLayout, because (AFAICT) TableLayout does not allow a view to span rows.  I'll see if I can get it to work by putting a Space in every cell.

Comment: BTW, while using Space views set to constant heights like that does keep views that are smaller than the desired grid still aligned to the grid properly, it doesn't keep views from sizing themselves to be bigger than the space you are trying to allocate to them, shoving other views off the right/bottom edges.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_columnSpan="1"
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_rowSpan="1"
```